# Drupal "People who read this article also read" module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

On the following [website](http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/cyprus-and-israel-sign-deal-demarcating-sea-borders-1.331160?localLinksEnabled=false) they have the following section "People who read this article also read" feature. Is this possible to do in Drupal? Is there a module for this or would I need to rely on something like [Similar Entries](http://drupal.org/node/25974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like what Netflix does for movies.  There's a nice chapter on how in "Programming Collective Intelligence"

Comment: Yep like netflix. Thanks I will see if we have a copy of the book in the office.

Comment: I can't recall if it's chapter 2 or 3 - I don't have a copy handy.